# how to make exe maker on run time

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this code, but it creates a dll file:

```
private void btnCompile_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CSharpCodeProvider csp = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler cc = csp.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

        cp.OutputAssembly = Application.StartupPath + "\\TestClass.dll";
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("CSharpScripter.exe");

        cp.WarningLevel = 3;

        cp.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize";
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        cp.GenerateInMemory = false;

        System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tfc = new TempFileCollection(Application.StartupPath, false);
        CompilerResults cr  = new CompilerResults(tfc);

        cr = cc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, this.rtfCode.Text);

        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0) 
        {
            foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ce.ErrorNumber + ": " + ce.ErrorText);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Errors occoured", "Errors", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.btnExecute.Enabled = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.btnExecute.Enabled = true;
        }

        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = cr.Output;
        foreach (string s in sc) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

How to convert to exe file?

Comment: You need `exe` or `dll`? If exe why do you name it as dll? If dll why do your question title says exe?

Answer (score 5):

```
cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
```

You probably [want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateexecutable.aspx) to change that line...

Comment: Might also want to change `/target:library` to `/target:winexe`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yaks5w33.aspx)

Comment: @icemanind: Or get rid of it entirely; I believe that that option is what this property sets.